# pandas: resample.apply discards index names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

For some reason doing `df.resample("M").apply(foo)` drops the index name in `df`. Is this expected behavior?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(60)}, index=pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01", periods=60))
df.index.name = "dte"
df.head()
#            a
#dte          
#2018-01-01  0
#2018-01-02  1
#2018-01-03  2
#2018-01-04  3
#2018-01-05  4
def f(x):
    print(x.head())

df.resample("M").apply(f)
#2018-01-01    0
#2018-01-02    1
#2018-01-03    2
#2018-01-04    3
#2018-01-05    4
#Name: a, dtype: int64
```

**update/clarification:**
When I said drops the name I meant that series received by the function doesn't have a name component associated with its index

Comment: For me it working nice in pandas `0.23.1`, so please upgrade your pandas.

Comment: i'm on `0.23.3`; you see my point though correct? that inside `f` the series that is passed to it does not have an index name

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use alternative of `resample` - `groupby` with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
def f(x):
    print(x.head())

df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).apply(f)
dte          
2018-01-01  0
2018-01-02  1
2018-01-03  2
2018-01-04  3
2018-01-05  4
            a
dte          
2018-01-01  0
2018-01-02  1
2018-01-03  2
2018-01-04  3
2018-01-05  4
             a
dte           
2018-02-01  31
2018-02-02  32
2018-02-03  33
2018-02-04  34
2018-02-05  35
```

Comment: @pyd - sure, give me some time.

Comment: @pyd - really not easy, half solution is done, but not yet completely... :(

Comment: @pyd - added better solution, no another ideas. It is better solution for easy reason - it loop only for `0` values and assigned `mean`s.

Comment: @pyd this seems completely unrelated to this question or the answer to this question

Comment: @Alex - How working solution? Another advantage of solution is it is faster like `.resample`

Comment: @jezrael sorry haven't tested it yet, just opened your answer. it seems resample is a pandas bug.. i think your solution will work well though. thanks for answering!